# Structuring database in firebase with one to many relation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, relational-database, nosql

It's the first time that I am making an application using Firebase. So I am new to NoSQL. Before that, I used mysql. How would I structure a table that related with more 1 table in firebase. It has a 'one to many' relation. My relation table looks like like diagram shown below:

[image]

and this is my structure, is this the correct way?

```
{
"car_rental" : {
    "car_rental_1" : {
        "name " : "A rent",
            "car" : {
                "car_id_1" : true       
            }
    }
},
"car" : {
    "car_id_1" : {
        "name" : "ABC",
        "colour" : "red"
        },
    "category" : {
        "car_category1" : true
        }
    },
"car_category" {
    "car_category1" : {
        "name" : "city car"
        },
    "car_category2" : {
        "name" : "SUV car"
        }
    }       
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make an attempt first. Show it here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Read these guides:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4

This is not an sql database, so the duplicating of data is not sin, it is a "requirement" because you have "unlimited" storage.

The main problem with your implementation is that you have to query the data from database, like in sql model, it is more simple if you just duplicate the data, like:

```
{  
   "car_rental":{  
      "car_rental_1":{  
         "name ":"A rent",
         "car_id_1":{  
            "name":"ABC",
            "colour":"red"
         },
         "category":{  
            "car_category1":true
         }
      }
   }
},
"car":{  
   "car_id_1":{  
      "name":"ABC",
      "colour":"red"
   },
   "category":{  
      "car_category1":true
   }
}
```

Comment: yes i've read, but the question is if what kind of json tree in firebase if i want to make structure like one to many from 2 table in firebase? @barotia

Comment: If you red that part, you have to know that there is not such a thing like  one to many in firebase database. The key is that you should reach approximately all of the necessary data, with minimized number of querying. In your structure, you have to query the data multiple times, which slows down the process of finding data.